# What permissions are needed to run an Azure Data Factory (ADF) debug session?

Tags: azure-data-factory

What are the Least Privilege permissions that are needed to run a debug session?
We have removed Data Factory Contributor because we want to disallow publishing to the dev instance by all developers, as is mentioned in the [Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#permissions).

> Only a select set of people should be allowed to publish to the
> factory. To do so, they must have the Data Factory contributor role on
> the resource group the factory is in.

However, [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/iterative-development-debugging) does not say what permissions are required to run Debug and we are getting the following error when trying to Debug a pipeline:
[image]

Related Documentation Issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/58517

Comment: what's the current role of your account?

Comment: That is a moot point. I can run Debug.  I'm looking for Least Privilege Access config for developers on my team.

Answer (score 1):

To create and manage child resources for Data Factory - including datasets, linked services, pipelines, triggers, and integration runtimes - the following requirements are applicable:

- To create and manage child resources in the Azure portal, you must
  belong to the **Data Factory Contributor** role at the resource group
  level or above.
- To create and manage child resources with PowerShell or the SDK, the
  **contributor** role at the resource level or above is sufficient.

Debug actually runs the pipeline, it also means manage the pipeline runs. As I understand, we need the **Data Factory Contributor** or **contributor** permission.

Ref: [Roles and requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-roles-permissions#roles-and-requirements)

As the [Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#permissions) document said:

- "Only a select set of people should be allowed to publish to the
  factory. To do so, they must have the Data Factory contributor role
  on the resource group the factory is in."

If you want to control the data factory permission of the developers, you could follow bellow steps:

1. Create AAD user group, and add the selected developers to
   the group.
2. Add the **Data Factory Contributor** or **contributor** role to the
   group. Then all the users in the group will have the permission.

   [image]

Ref: [Create a basic group and add members using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for the least privilege permissions.  I just updated the question to clarify that.  I do not want to give all developers Data Factory Contributor access.

Comment: @successhawk  Yeah, as I said in answer,  you could add some of the developers not all the developers to the group! The least privilege permission is `reader`. Some other ways you can try to add a custom role: if the Azure built-in roles don't meet the specific needs of your organization, you can create your own Azure custom roles. ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-portal

Comment: @successhawk If all of these couldn't meet your request, the best way is that ask Azure Support for help. Maybe they can give your more suggestions.  In the end, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @successhawk do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Your answer may be helpful to others, but it doesn't answer the question.  I obviously already new that Data Factory Contributor would allow debugging, but I clearly stated that it gave too much permission to assign to all developers.  A custom role is needed, and I am asking for the Least Privilege permissions/actions that are needed to perform debugging.